# React Native Fade In Animation is not smooth

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, animation

I'm creating an animation similar to [www.icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com) sign in. Which means when user type his/her email, the password box appears with a fade in animation.Below is what I want to achieve.

[image: Animation I want to achieve]

**My Code**

However to do that I created below code.

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
}

state ={
    hideEmail:false,
} 

animate () {
this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
Animated.timing(
  this.animatedValue,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: Easing.linear
  }
 ).start()
}

render() {

const marginTop = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, 100]
})

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{paddingBottom:10}}>
      <TextInput 
        placeholder='Registered Email' 
        returnKeyType='go'
        style={{borderWidth:0.5}}
        onSubmitEditing = {(event) => this.getData()}>
      </TextInput>
    </View>
    <Animated.View style={{marginTop,opacity:!this.state.hideEmail?0:1}}>
      <TextInput 
        placeholder='Code' 
        style={{borderWidth:0.5}}>
      </TextInput>
    </Animated.View>
  </View>
);

getData = (email) => {
  // Validate and if it's correct email, below code will run
  this.animate();
  this.setState({hideEmail:true});
}
```

Here I've used `hideEmail` state to change opacity of `Code` View to make it hide and visible. However what this does is, when user type the email, it will be validated and rest of the code of getData() will run and start the animation with making `Code View` visible.

**Problems**

There are two problems.

[image: Problems of Animation]

As you can see, when the email types (I did not validate it properly. Just to show how this works) and enters, code box appears and start to animate. But have two problems.

1) First box (Email Box) also moves with Code box.

2) Animation is not smooth. Borderline appears and disappears. Which is annoying and not beautiful.

So how can I fix them? I tried everything by changing my code, but nothing worked.

Comment: Add your styles also with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven’t posted styles with your code, I guess  the container that contains both of your TextInputs must be justified to center.

Just check whether your container contains following code.

```
JustifyContent: ‘center’
```

If so, remove it and add a marginTop to your first TextInput box. Movement will as you expected.

Comment: Oh I see. Removing justifyContent did the trick. But what about the decaying of border width?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but whenever this Animation happens, still border width doesn’t decrease in my situation .